# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND when I request with axios

Tags: javascript, axios, request

I'm trying to get some numeric values from https://magiceden.io/. I'm using their API for this job. I've read the docs and it tells me to use this curl command to get the data.

```
curl --location --request GET api-devnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/blocksmith_labs/stats
```

when I run it on my WSL I get the data perfectly as here:

```
{"symbol":"blocksmith_labs","floorPrice":48950000000,"listedCount":66,"avgPrice24hr":50442414285.71429,"volumeAll":254720729764252}
```

but when I try to create the same request with axios I got an error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

here's my attempt to get the data with axios

```
const axios = require("axios").default
let display = document.getElementById("display")

export async function getCollectionData() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get("api- 
mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/collections/blocksmith_labs/stats");
        console.log(response)
        display.textContent = response
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

can someone help me with this?

Comment: ```https://api-mainnet.magiceden/...```  works for me ... if i state the protocol https

Comment: I guess that was the problem, thank you so much sir! You can add the answer